# Apollo Query doesn't make request

Tags: reactjs, apollo

Apollo query doesn't make a request. I am totally new with this technology, maybe some could tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
    state = { news: [] };

    render() {
        <Query query={GET_NEWS}>
            {({ loading, error, data}) => {
              if (loading) {
                return null;
              }

              if (error) {
                return `Error: ${error}`;
              }
              const news = data.news.name
          return (
          <div>
            {news.map(item => <div>{item.name}</div>)}
          </div>
          );
         }}
      </Query>
  }
}
```

Query doesn't get any type nor loading, error or data.

my GET_NEWS constant.

```
export const GET_NEWS = gql`
  {
    news(query: {}){
         edges{
          name
        }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Have you correctly configured an apollo-client instance and a wrapped your with an `ApolloProvider` as per the docs?

Comment: Please provide your query of `GET_NEWS `?

Comment: @SivadassN, added query. Daniel, did the wrapping, my console says that render returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing return inside `render`:

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
state = { news: [] };

render() {
 return(
    <Query query={GET_NEWS}>
        {({ loading, error, data}) => {
          if (loading) {
            return null;
          }

          if (error) {
            return `Error: ${error}`;
          }
          const news = data.news.name
      return (
      <div>
        {news.map(item => <div>{item.name}</div>)}
      </div>
      );
     }}
  </Query>
 )
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't notice that!